# What is the link to your answer?

Tags: code-golf, parsing, internet, self-referential

### Goal

Your task is to create a program taking no input that returns the link to your answer. You can find a link to your answer by clicking at the share button on your answer.

### Rules

1. Standard loopholes apply except for searching for the answer online. In fact, you are expected to find the answer online.
2. You are allowed to use curl or the equivalent, but you are not allowed to use any html parser library or built-in. If you need to import the library, the import declaration does **NOT** count into the code size as long as you don't rename any identifiers.
3. **You are not allowed to assume, or hardcode, the link to your answer**. You have to search this page for your submission. If you remove your submission and re-add it, and your code breaks, you fail the challenge.
4. You may still assume your username, the contents of your code, and the programming language/byte count you are using. You are not allowed to assume the description below your code. If you edit the description part of the submission and the code breaks, you fail the challenge. You may assume that the code of each submission is unique and no one copies your submission into another answer.
5. Your answer has to be exactly the same as what you get when you clicked on the share button.
6. You may post the dummy answer for the prototyping purpose. Just delete it immediately after posting, and edit your answer into it once completed.
7. You are not allowed to take an user input

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so, the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: BAN URL SHORTENERS before anyone has a 'clever idea'.

Comment: I added a couple of bits to the text. Namely, bolded the bit about requiring it to *fetch* the answer rather than hardcode, and changed the placeholder bit to tell users to delete their answer (your deleted answers are still visible to you), then edit in their actual submission

Comment: "taking the input that returns the link to your answer"? Do you mean "taking no input"?

Comment: "not allowed to use any html parser library", may I use a browser? Or say [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "taking the input that returns the link to your answer."? By my understanding, we should write a program which uses the internet to find our own answer on this page, and output a link to it. There should be no input necessary. Is this correct, and if not, what is?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing fixed. No input.

Comment: May we hard-code our user ID (that goes on the end of the link)?

Comment: @pxeger there seems to be a consensus in the existing answers (even before I posted) that the user ID should be discarded, probably because it changes for every person clicking on the "share" link. IMO this is also a good idea because we have already a byte count advantage for the users with a shorter ID, and the cost for adding it at the end of the string is fixed for any answer given a language

Comment: @Kaddath should I edit the answer to take account of that suggestion?

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>61</s> 57 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¦ɦḍɓḃɠṭṢ⁽&½ṛøHØÐ»Ȯ;⁾q/;“£ɓ⁶’ŒGœṣ“"/a/”iƇ”ɦṪṣ”=-3ịḊḣ6⁾a/;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDy04ue7ij9@TkhzuaTy54uHPtw52LHjXuVTu09@HO2Yd3eByecXjCod0n1lk/atxXqG8N0rH45ORHjdseNcw8Osn96OSHOxcDBZX0E/UfNczNPNYOJIEm7lwFFp9rq2v8cHf3wx1dD3csNgMakahv/f8/AA)

What's a worse idea than parsing HTML with regex? Parsing HTML with *Jelly*

This outputs `codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226641`. This will fail if this is "reposted" after ~780000 more posts are posted to the site, but that is currently 3.5 times the number of posts we currently have. A more future-proof version comes out as [the same length](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDy04ue7ij9@TkhzuaTy54uHPtw52LHjXuVTu09@HO2Yd3eByecXjCod0n1lk/atxXqG8N0rH45ORHjdseNcw8Osn96OSHOxcDBZX0E/UfNczNPNYOJIEm7lwFFp9rq2v8cHd32uEZLkD9ifrW//8DAA)

### How it works

This works in two parts. First we build and print the string to fetch the HTML of the question (including the answers), then we process and extract my answer id

```
“¦ɦḍɓḃɠṭṢ⁽&½ṛøHØÐ»Ȯ;⁾q/;“£ɓ⁶’ŒG - Main link
“¦ɦḍɓḃɠṭṢ⁽&½ṛøHØÐ»              - Compressed string "codegolf.stackexchange.com/"
                  Ȯ             - Print this
                   ;⁾q/         - Concatenate "q/"
                        “£ɓ⁶’   - Compressed integer: 226635
                       ;        - Concatenate; "codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226635"
                             ŒG - GET request, prepending "http://"
```

Building the string this way takes 2 more bytes than simply compressing `codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/226635`: [`“ñoHƑ;ɦŻt%WɓḤȦ3æḶ2ỤƭȮ¦1ẈA»`](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//4oCcw7FvSMaRO8mmxbt0JVfJk@G4pMimM8Om4bi2MuG7pMatyK7CpjHhuohBwrv//w). However, by having `“¦ɦḍɓḃɠṭṢ⁽&½ṛøHØÐ»` (`"codegolf.stackexchange.com/"`) by itself at the start, we can print it using `Ȯ`, allowing us to just output `a/226641` later on

```
œṣ“"/a/”iƇ”ɦṪṣ”=-3ịḊḣ6⁾a/; - Main link.
                             To our left, we have the HTML content of this page
  “"/a/”                   - Yield '"/a/'
œṣ                         - Split at '"/a/', splitting roughly into answers
        iƇ”ɦ               - Keep those with the "ɦ" character in them. Currently, that's just me
            Ṫ              - Extract this bit of HTML
             ṣ”=           - Split at equals signs
                -3ị        - Take the 4th from last, which is '"226641">    <div class'
                   Ḋ       - Remove the quote
                    ḣ6     - Extract the first 6 characters
                   fØD     - Future proof version: keep only digits
                      ⁾a/; - Prepend "a/" and output
```

Comment: 57 unicode characters != 57 bytes

Comment: @Tim Yes, but no. Jelly uses a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) to represent all single byte values as printable characters. The exact byte stream of this program is `fe 05 a0 d5 9b e7 9f e0 b7 8d 26 0a de 1d 48 12 0f fb ca 3b 8e 71 2f 3b fe 02 9b 86 fd 13 47 1e df fe 22 2f 61 2f ff 69 90 ff a0 ce df ff 3d 2d 33 d8 c1 ed 36 8e 61 2f 3b ` (57 bytes). You can represent this as UTF-8 characters, but it isn't pretty, so Jelly uses its own code page to make it more "readable"

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ahhhhh. Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I thought I had lost my mind. Like "how are all these programmers unaware that unicode is 2 bytes per char?". haha.

Comment: (@Tim Unicode is [not 2 bytes per character](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen0) though.)

Comment: Fails for me in TIO

Comment: @Seggan That's because it requires an internet connection (to do the GET request), and TIO is sandboxed so that programs can't connect to the internet: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEotbA0tbikmIsLxtJLTy3RUM8oKSkottLXT61IzC3ISdVLzs9V1/z/HwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (Browser Console), 155 bytes

```javascript
alert(`${c='https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/'}a/${(await(await fetch(c+`search?q=user:${u=44718}+inquestion:226635`)).text()).match(/(?<=s#)\d+/)}/${u}`)
```

I'm using Firefox 88. The code need to be executed under same domain due to permission restriction of fetch.

Btw, top level await is allowed in most browsers' console.

Comment: <s>I'm not sure why this may fail as search result cannot find out this post...</s> OK, finally get to work, seems search result has some latency...

Comment: remove last `${u}` and add a +u ad the end. saves 2 bytes.

Comment: You don't need the user ID in the final URL at all.

Comment: [143 bytes](https://bit.ly/2S3X2iW)

Comment: @EliteDaMyth "missing ) after argument list?"

Comment: @ophact the code runs fine for me as is

Comment: @EliteDaMyth it was showing on TIO

Comment: @ophact, oh the code isnt meant to be run on tio, its for the browser console

Comment: [135 bytes, but only works on codegolf.stackexchange.com in the browser console](https://bit.ly/3wH9cNs)

Comment: @EliteDaMyth `location.host` is much elder (widely supported) and also shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 151 byte

```
r: :rejoin n:"104280"u: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ r[u"a/"parse read r[u"questions/226635"][collect[thru[{"}ahead[22 skip n]]keep to{"}]]"/"n]
```

No TIO link, since it uses an outdated toolchain and errors out during lexing. Try it [locally](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html) instead, using the latest automated build.

---

Red's implementation of GZIP and DEFLATE decompression is completely broken, so, instead of working with [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression), I had to fall back on HTML parsing... which is a nice showcase in its own regard, since the solution relies on the embedded PEG parsing DSL.

Comment: " you are not allowed to use any html parser library or built-in " Does this rely on a html parser library or is the parse DSL only used inside your program?

Comment: @Wzl, it's an [embedded domain-specific language](https://www.red-lang.org/2013/11/041-introducing-parse.html), not an HTML parsing library. I'm not quite sure what OP means by "built-in": technically, _everything_ in the standard library is a built-in.

Comment: I understand that, I mean if there was any external anything specifically for parsing HTML that you used. It looks like not (so +1).

Comment: I'll amend that to +6 ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) 5, 211 bytes

```php
foreach(json_decode(gzdecode(join(file('http://api'.($s='.stackexchange.com/').'2.2/questions/226635/answers?site=codegolf'))))->items as$i)if($i->owner->user_id==90841)echo"https://codegolf{$s}a/$i->answer_id";
```

[(Cannot) Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7dboMwDIVfZaqQklyQbGxD@4M@ShUFQ0zbOMNBTKv67DSomy8s68jnOyf6uH7tY949TWCdlyNTOHTgqAM5/P4dI2GQPZ5ACp9S/DDGRhRaFtwIzcm6I/w4b8MA2tHZCKVFpSvzPQMnpMCmqur6@dXYwAtMvGdM0GzkgU69UHnKNktnfrBcoMJeFli2tASYynZmmA7YNc3749vLkwLnabe14Fzjn3Ep@GrNZrpH5P/d57reAA)

Unfortunately, `file` and `gzdecode` functions re disabled in PHP online testers, but it works so far on my localhost

**EDIT:** first version didn't work (because of the content of my own answer, lol) and was easy to break with a single comment, switched to a supposedly foolproof version with the API, much longer though

**EDIT 2:** saved 5 bytes with strings optimizations

**EDIT 3:** another byte saved (the dust) by using `http` instead of `https` for the API

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](//golang.org), 342 bytes

```go
package main
import(."encoding/json"
."net/http")
func main(){t,u:="codegolf",".stackexchange.com/"
r,_:=Get("https://api"+u+"2.2/questions/226635/answers?site="+t)
var s struct{Items[]struct{Answer_ID int
Owner struct{User_ID int}}}
NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&s)
for _,i:=range s.Items{if i.Owner.User_ID==7815{print(t,u,"a/",i.Answer_ID)}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) + [Sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 114 bytes (104 bytes + 5 byte user ID twice)

```bash
U=https://codegolf.stackexchange.com
wget $U/q/226635 -O-|sed -nE '/44694/s?.*answer-([0-9]+).*?'$U'/a/\1/44694?p'
```

Prints `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226723/44694` on stdout.

Note that `wget` prints logs to stderr, which should be ignored.

(No TIO link because wget doesn't work on TIO; I assume TIO blocks internet access.)

Explanation:

- Save the string `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com` in `$U`
- `wget` the webpage for this question, piping it to `sed`
- Using `sed`:

  - Search for all lines containing my user ID.
  - (Specifically we are looking for the line containing `<div
    id="answer-XXXX" class="answer" data-answerid="XXXX"
    data-ownerid="YYYY" ...`, where `YYYY`
    is my user ID, and `XXXX` is the answer ID we are
    looking for.)
  - If the line contains `answer-XXXX`, then

    - The `XXXX` is the answer ID; capture it in a subexpression.
    - Print the string saved in `$U` followed by `/a/`, followed by the answer ID using `\1` subexpression replacement, followed by a slash and my user ID.

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) + [Sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 100 bytes (95 bytes + 5 byte user ID)

If the output format is not as strict, then I have a 100 byte version that prints the URL without the `https://` or the trailing user ID.

Prints `codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226723` on stdout.

```bash
U=codegolf.stackexchange.com
wget $U/q/226635 -O-|sed -nE '/44694/s?.*answer-([0-9]+).*?'$U'/a/\1?p'
```

- -8 bytes: no `https://`
- -(1+5) bytes: no trailing `/` and user ID

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 216 bytes

```js
fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/226635/answers?site=codegolf").then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>"https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/"+j.items.find(a=>a.owner.user_id==17602).answer_id).then(console.log)
```

Comment: You can [require that the code be run from within the API's domain](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/) and also [return a `Promise` that contains the output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/).

Comment: @Shaggy Sure, but it makes for a better Stack Snippet this way...

Comment: This is giving me https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226641 , which is incorrect.

Comment: @Wzl Thanks, I was missing an `=`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 60 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ’žYì©…/q/•3{Ä•J.w“"/a/“¡ʒ'ʒå}`'=¡4(èþ'a®rŽÍ¿'/ý
```

Port of [*@cairdCoinheringaahing*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226641/52210), so make sure to upvote him.
Assumes this is the only answer that contains a `ʒ`. If another answer should pop up with this character, it could be switched to another unique character from my program that probably isn't used in a lot of languages instead, like `þ` or `®`.

No TIO of the entire program, since `.w` is disabled.

**Explanation:**

Generate the question URL, and get its HTML content:

```python
’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ’     # Push dictionary string "codegolf.stackexchange.com"
  žYì              # Prepend "https://"
     ©             # Store this string in variable `®` (without popping)
      …/q/         # Push string "/q/"
          •3{Ä•    # Push compressed integer 226635
               J   # Join the entire stack together
                .w # Browse to this URL and get its HTML content as string
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMY5MOdx9dcLpN73DTo4ZZjxp2Htqld3TS0UlAqaP7Ig@vObTyUcMy/UL9Rw2LjKsPtwApr///AQ) (without `.w`).

And then get the answer-ID and generate the resulting URL:

```python
“"/a/“¡           "# Split the HTML content on '"/a/'
       ʒ           # Filter these parts by:
        'ʒå       '#  Check if it contains character "ʒ"
       }`          # After the filter: pop and push this only part to the stack
         '=¡      '# Split it on "="
            4(è    # Index to get the 0-based -4'th item (fourth item from the back)
               þ   # Only leave its digits
'a                '# Push string "a"
  ®                # Push the string from variable `®`
   r               # Reverse the three values on the stack
    ŽÍ¿            # Push compressed integer 52210
       '/ý        '# Join the stack with "/" delimiter
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The URL generated by TIO would be too big for a stackexchange answer and most URL-shorteners unfortunately, so here the TIO where you'll have to insert the question's HTML content yourself (Ctrl+U in your browser, select everything, and past it between the `"""` in the input-block of the TIO):
['Try it online.'](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYeaxSYe7jy443aZ3uOlRw6xHDTsP7dI7OunoJKDU0X2Rh9ccWvmoYZl@of6jhkXG1YdbgJRXDFDfHCX9RKDYnEMLT01SPzXp8NLaBHXbQwtNNA6vOLxPPfHQuqKjew/3Htqvrn947///SkpKXB4hvj7xzv5@Ia5@IfHu/q7B8R6uQa5cQCkA)

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how `’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ’` is `"codegolf.stackexchange.com"`; `•3{Ä•` is `226635`; and `ŽÍ¿` is `52210`.